# where is symfony2 formerror class/component?

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I am doing the following in my controller to manually check a form, now I get an error saying

Fatal error: Class 'BizTV\ContentManagementBundle\Controller\formerror' not found in /var/www/cloudsign_beta/src/BizTV/ContentManagementBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on line 233

so I suppose there is a fancy symfony form component I must add with a USE statement on top, anyone know which one?

```
    if ($nameOccupied=1) {          
        $error = new formerror("Det finns redan innehåll på denna plats med samma namn, vänligen välj ett annat namn (eller välj en annan plats).");
        $form->get('name')->addError($error);   
    }
```

Comment: [`use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormError.html)

Comment: cheese you might wanna add this as an answer for him to be able to accept it :)

Comment: @nifr Well, I always feel like a short answer like this one fits best in a comment but I did post it as CW so he can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the following `use` statement:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError
```

Reference: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormError.html

**Important**: When creating an object, you should use the same case than the one from the class definition to avoid failure on case sensitive systems.
Here, `new formerror` should be `new FormError`

Comment: Be aware to call new FormError (notice camelcase) otherwise it will fail on casesentive systems.